# How to restore a site from a backup done with Backup and Migrate module using Drush

Tags: drush, backups

Just that. I've a backup using the [backup and migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate). I've done some changes and now the site is down. I can't restore the site using the admin interface (because it's broken).

Can I use Drush to restore it?

Comment: Just as a side note, BAM backups can usually also be restored with normal MySQL administration tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can restore your backup with Drush.

Here are Backup and Migrate commands for Drush explained: http://www.only10types.com/2011/03/drush-backup-and-migrate-command.html

I think drush bam-restore command is what you are looking for.

> bam-restore Restore the site's database with Backup and Migrate.
>
> Examples: drush bam-restore db manual
>   "LCC-31.03.2011-14.01.59.mysql.gz" - restore the default database
>   using the given dump file, which can be found in the destination
>   called "manual"
>
> Arguments: source - Required. The id of the source (usually a
>   database) to restore the backup to. Use 'drush bam-sources' to get a
>   list of sources. Defaults to 'db' destination - Required. The id of
>   destination to send the backup file to. Use 'drush bam-destinations'
>   to get a list of destinations. Defaults to 'manual' backup id -
>   Required. The id of a backup file restore. Use 'drush bam-backups' to
>   get a list of available backup files.

Comment: What if the dump file is on the filesystem and not in the bam list

Comment: It appears that drush bam-restore only handles db backups. I think you will need to extract the files tar.gz file manually (without using drush).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but for completeness' sake I'd rather add the official bam-backup command help too.

```
$ drush help bam-backup

Backup the site's database using default settings.

Examples:
 drush bam-backup                          Backup the default database to the manual backup directory using the default settings.                                                            
 drush bam-backup db scheduled mysettings  Backup the database to the scheduled directory using a settings profile called "mysettings"                                                       
 drush bam-backup files                    Backup the files directory to the manual directory using the default settings. The Backup and Migrate Files module is required for files backups.

Arguments:
 source                                    Optional. The id of the source (usually a database) to backup. Use 'drush bam-sources' to get a list of sources. Defaults to 'db'            
 destination                               Optional. The id of destination to send the backup file to. Use 'drush bam-destinations' to get a list of destinations. Defaults to 'manual' 
 profile                                   Optional. The id of a settings profile to use. Use 'drush bam-profiles' to get a list of available profiles. Defaults to 'default'

Aliases: bb
```